# How do I create a VirtualHost on Zend Server?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I am using zend server and I added one VirtualHost into the extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file and removed # from the httpd.conf file.

This is what I added into the extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName quickstart.local
    DocumentRoot D:/quickstart/Code


    <Directory D:/quickstart/Code>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I access quickstart.local it is working fine, but it also affects localhost (i.e when I try to load http://localhost/, I see the same site I do for http://quickstart.local/.

How do I resolve this issue? I want both localhost (I use this for another project) and quickstart.local to be separate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same problem. Try to add a host to zend.conf or
add

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

to htppd.conf

Comment: Uncomment the line: Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in htppd.conf file and add your directives to the httpd-vhosts.conf located accordingly in C:\Program Files...\Zend\Apache2\conf\extra directory.

Comment: In windows you might also need to add a line to your hosts file

Answer (score 3):

You can add a new vhost by adding the directives to a new file:

```
/path/to/zend/etc/sites.d/vhost_[my-site].conf
```

Replace `[my-site]` with whatever you want (no spaces).

Then, be sure you **restart apache**:

```
sudo /path/to/zend/bin/apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when trying to add own sites. Solution for me was to comment both vhost examples in vhosts file and also uncomment or add the

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

into hosts file in %windir%/system32/drivers/etc folder

... ofcourse if you need to uncomment vhost_alias module and include for httpd-vhosts file..

Answer (score 0):

> [FILE PATH] \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf or, if you are
>   using Apache 2.4 or above:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName dev.zendapp
     DocumentRoot "G:/xampp/htdocs/io2018/zend2018/zendApps"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "G:/xampp/htdocs/io2018/zend2018/zendApps">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

> After change. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1       dev.zendapp
```

> Restart Your xampp Server