# Subdomain configuration

Tags: zend-framework, routes, subdomain, virtualhost

I use zend-framework 1.12
My application's quick start path is project.local

I can use zend-framework host rout in localhost.

I can't access username.project.local.
username.projetc.local is routed project.local/default/users/profile/uname/username

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add in `xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.cnf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "opt/lampp/htdocs/your_project_directory" 
 ServerName username.project.local
</VirtualHost>
```

if you are using windows add windows/system32/drivers/etc/host file entry

```
127.0.0.1 username.project.local
```

or see this [How do I create a VirtualHost on Zend Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460296/how-do-i-create-a-virtualhost-on-zend-server)

hope this will help you.